# Is "want someone to do" double objects?

Tags: complements, objects

This might be double objects or an object with a complement.

Which is right?

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is neither double objects nor an object with a complement, but is a complex sentence, combined from two separate simpler sentences.

Let's take the concrete example "I want Tom to do his homework".

This comes down to: "I want X", where X = "Tom (to) do his homework".

"I want X" is the main clause, and "Tom (to) do his homework" is the subordinate clause, which takes the place of the object of the verb "want".

And in the subordinate clause, "Tom" is the subject, "do" is the verb -- cast into the infinitive "to do" because it is in a subordinate clause -- and "his homework" is the object.

Comment: I thaught subordinate clauses all  were full sentences starting with that, who, or something like that. It's the first time that I know "Tom to do his homework" is a subordinate clause. It may take time to understand it. I will search more articles about what you said.